# Colorbar and contour plot seem to not match data; individual/custom scale to emphasize data of interest

Tags: scale, colorbar, contourf

I am trying to create a contour plot that shows the turbulence intensity of a measurement plane. However, towards the bottom the values are very high (about 45%) while the values are about 2-10% in the majority of the plane. Due to the scale of the colourbar, it is impossible to see any variation in the range of interest (2-10%). [Example Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJwHT.png)

I want the colourbar to go from 2 to 5% with a large colour gradient and the gradient should decrease quite rapidly, so that the colour change between 30-45% is very small.

I have tried adding custom normalization to have an individual scale for the colorbar. However, it does not seem to match the contour plot colours. I.e. it appears that the value is closer to 10-15% than 2-10%. Based on the data, the colour should be mostly dark purple.

[Contour bar and Contour Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEBOO.png)

**I have added the ContourMatrix to the end of the question.** Interested in the far right column which contains turbulence intensity.

```
ContourMatrix = np.loadtxt(data_str.splitlines())
print(ContourMatrix)
# Assuming ContourMatrix is already created in Python
x = ContourMatrix[:, 0]
y = ContourMatrix[:, 1]
values_ti = ContourMatrix[:, 4]  # Adjusted variable name

# Define grid for interpolation
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100), np.linspace(0.4, -0.4, 100))  # Adjusted limits for Y-axis
Z = griddata((x, y), values_ti, (X, Y), method='linear')


# Custom normalization
class MidpointLogNormalize(Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # Use np.where to perform array-wise comparison
        return np.where(value <= self.midpoint,
                        np.log10(1 + value) / np.log10(1 + self.midpoint) * 0.5,
                        (value - self.midpoint) / (self.vmax - self.midpoint) * 0.5 + 0.5)


# Create filled contour plot
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap='plasma', alpha=1, norm=MidpointLogNormalize(vmin=2, vmax=45, midpoint=4))

# Add colorbar with custom ticks and labels
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=MidpointLogNormalize(vmin=2, vmax=45, midpoint=4), cmap='plasma'))
cbar_ticks = [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 45]
cbar.set_ticks(cbar_ticks)
cbar.set_ticklabels([str(tick) for tick in cbar_ticks])

# Add markers
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1, c='k', marker='+', alpha=1.0)

# Plot circle
radius = 0.3
circle = Circle((0, 0), radius, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1, fill=False)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

# Plot dot at the center of the circle
plt.plot(0, 0, 'ko', markersize=4)
```

**Data for ContourMatrix:**
data_str = """
-0.4    0.4 0.630885915 -1.471062283    3.0963
-0.3    0.4 0.632192906 -1.266942184    2.992
-0.2    0.4 0.637319087 -0.466358223    2.8618
-0.1    0.4 0.633302477 -1.093654463    2.8855
0   0.4 0.635165409 -0.802709989    2.9681
0.1 0.4 0.634795151 -0.860535194    2.9951
0.2 0.4 0.636487265 -0.596268496    2.8705
0.3 0.4 0.627690599 -1.970092336    3.1598
0.4 0.4 0.623768592 -2.582613947    3.1787
-0.4    0.35    0.629567053 -1.677036206    3.224
-0.3    0.35    0.634046212 -0.977501226    3.1507
-0.2    0.35    0.635387453 -0.768032245    2.999
-0.1    0.35    0.626372803 -2.17589993 3.1514
0   0.35    0.632440342 -1.228298777    3.1271
0.1 0.35    0.627662835 -1.974428378    3.304
0.2 0.35    0.634352021 -0.929741268    2.9069
0.3 0.35    0.626872068 -2.097926885    3.2108
0.4 0.35    0.628126802 -1.901968169    3.287
-0.4    0.3 0.63704614  -0.508985896    3.071
-0.3    0.3 0.637584642 -0.424885031    3.0268
-0.2    0.3 0.63705201  -0.508069211    2.9359
-0.1    0.3 0.634751724 -0.867317492    3.0556
0   0.3 0.635102241 -0.812575265    3.0564
0.1 0.3 0.635030214 -0.823824107    3.125
0.2 0.3 0.631624304 -1.355743927    3.1241
0.3 0.3 0.63144034  -1.384474593    3.1036
0.4 0.3 0.633676606 -1.035224549    2.9999
-0.4    0.25    0.642653445 0.366737869 3.0636
-0.3    0.25    0.638091526 -0.345722157    3.2556
-0.2    0.25    0.634442654 -0.915586637    3.2961
-0.1    0.25    0.63651472  -0.591980644    3.0586
0   0.25    0.634593256 -0.892066336    3.2577
0.1 0.25    0.630942017 -1.46230042 3.3458
0.2 0.25    0.637138037 -0.494633845    3.0924
0.3 0.25    0.633445041 -1.071389479    3.1995
0.4 0.25    0.637793273 -0.392302056    3.0744
-0.4    0.2 0.641006945 0.109594874 3.6334
-0.3    0.2 0.638107924 -0.343161232    3.209
-0.2    0.2 0.640731073 0.066510523 3.0375
-0.1    0.2 0.639403357 -0.140846357    3.1376
0   0.2 0.635579333 -0.738065225    3.073
0.1 0.2 0.635120948 -0.809653699    3.2691
0.2 0.2 0.636402262 -0.609543813    3.2768
0.3 0.2 0.633995949 -0.98535112 3.1529
0.4 0.2 0.641001197 0.10869714  3.1434
-0.4    0.15    0.643655899 0.523296721 3.2212
-0.3    0.15    0.639846469 -0.071642991    3.1498
-0.2    0.15    0.642219509 0.298967685 2.8616
-0.1    0.15    0.638379964 -0.300675205    2.97
0   0.15    0.634018808 -0.981781085    2.9237
0.1 0.15    0.634784929 -0.862131724    3.1708
0.2 0.15    0.639326577 -0.152837499    3.0186
0.3 0.15    0.638843954 -0.228211397    3.1993
0.4 0.15    0.642762827 0.383820648 3.2515
-0.4    0.1 0.645503745 0.811885063 3.2578
-0.3    0.1 0.641111485 0.125921448 3.2283
-0.2    0.1 0.640866267 0.087624488 3.1917
-0.1    0.1 0.638843474 -0.228286284    3.1175
0   0.1 0.637066145 -0.505861526    3.0232
0.1 0.1 0.636763758 -0.553087061    3.2674
0.2 0.1 0.638299075 -0.313308136    3.1311
0.3 0.1 0.640458313 0.023911952 3.3096
0.4 0.1 0.646422105 0.955310404 3.1992
-0.4    0.05    0.648097041 1.216894312 3.149
-0.3    0.05    0.642854056 0.39806841  3.1531
-0.2    0.05    0.64008754  -0.033993603    3.1353
-0.1    0.05    0.640298822 -0.000996523    3.1371
0   0.05    0.637865228 -0.381064411    3.0532
0.1 0.05    0.636527439 -0.589994266    3.2595
0.2 0.05    0.642321423 0.314884234 3.0926
0.3 0.05    0.641557652 0.195601813 3.3811
0.4 0.05    0.64632485  0.940121506 3.2858
-0.4    0   0.648701893 1.31135742  3.4873
-0.3    0   0.645172667 0.760178748 3.1737
-0.2    0   0.646496325 0.966901726 3.2042
-0.1    0   0.642805802 0.390532394 3.7
0   0   0.640305203 0   3.5371
0.1 0   0.641828781 0.23794554  3.1187
0.2 0   0.644035831 0.58263274  3.2823
0.3 0   0.644523637 0.658816118 3.437
0.4 0   0.649479391 1.432783526 3.2857
-0.4    -0.025  0.651434721 1.738158314 2.8956
-0.3    -0.025  0.645531302 0.816188792 2.9571
-0.2    -0.025  0.64465278  0.678985142 2.8816
-0.1    -0.025  0.643467255 0.493835097 3.1362
0   -0.025  0.642717614 0.376759466 2.9246
0.1 -0.025  0.645599724 0.82687462  3.3345
0.2 -0.025  0.644311903 0.625748376 3.0815
0.3 -0.025  0.646510502 0.969115762 3.3188
0.4 -0.025  0.645712188 0.844438674 3.103
-0.4    -0.05   0.652890176 1.965464694 2.8384
-0.3    -0.05   0.645166278 0.759180867 2.9127
-0.2    -0.05   0.64509292  0.747724199 2.9008
-0.1    -0.05   0.641216363 0.142300897 3.1307
0   -0.05   0.642555096 0.351378201 2.9185
0.1 -0.05   0.642409123 0.328580848 3.288
0.2 -0.05   0.646020485 0.892587135 3.0798
0.3 -0.05   0.647227201 1.081046675 3.2599
0.4 -0.05   0.646681766 0.995863059 3.0768
-0.4    -0.075  0.653491214 2.05933219  2.9673
-0.3    -0.075  0.645853687 0.866537326 2.9752
-0.2    -0.075  0.644676352 0.682666447 2.9541
-0.1    -0.075  0.642392409 0.325970448 3.2064
0   -0.075  0.64103929  0.114646392 3.0371
0.1 -0.075  0.642892503 0.404072852 3.4156
0.2 -0.075  0.645344222 0.786971454 3.1753
0.3 -0.075  0.647349544 1.100153623 3.2898
0.4 -0.075  0.646217701 0.923387377 3.1919
-0.4    -0.1    0.65109581  1.685228708 2.7311
-0.3    -0.1    0.643833728 0.551069266 2.532
-0.2    -0.1    0.642516969 0.345423624 2.4883
-0.1    -0.1    0.640527986 0.034793283 2.5604
0   -0.1    0.642617612 0.361141739 2.4991
0.1 -0.1    0.642064934 0.274826867 3.0925
0.2 -0.1    0.641717351 0.220542944 2.7287
0.3 -0.1    0.644166175 0.602989301 2.7916
0.4 -0.1    0.644805156 0.702782503 2.8243
-0.4    -0.125  0.651617997 1.766781432 2.9317
-0.3    -0.125  0.645298265 0.779794123 2.6988
-0.2    -0.125  0.642863927 0.399610016 2.5821
-0.1    -0.125  0.639138105 -0.182272123    2.6409
0   -0.125  0.64295935  0.41451276  2.6595
0.1 -0.125  0.642381621 0.324285662 3.092
0.2 -0.125  0.643560726 0.508432914 2.8325
0.3 -0.125  0.646791034 1.01292804  2.9457
0.4 -0.125  0.645864374 0.868206414 2.923
-0.4    -0.15   0.654270406 2.181022807 3.6171
-0.3    -0.15   0.64799804  1.20143282  3.5756
-0.2    -0.15   0.646509956 0.969030501 3.4272
-0.1    -0.15   0.643243579 0.458902317 3.5406
0   -0.15   0.65281968  1.954454979 3.3512
0.1 -0.15   0.640140435 -0.0257328  3.6819
0.2 -0.15   0.645085667 0.746591382 3.6905
0.3 -0.15   0.650328773 1.565436276 3.6901
0.4 -0.15   0.649195316 1.388418008 3.5596
-0.4    -0.175  0.655300121 2.341839117 4.2073
-0.3    -0.175  0.647200563 1.076886467 4.3684
-0.2    -0.175  0.64477966  0.698800651 4.0358
-0.1    -0.175  0.642188306 0.294094602 4.2177
0   -0.175  0.653991563 2.137474371 4.0795
0.1 -0.175  0.644210515 0.60991412  4.3667
0.2 -0.175  0.646580249 0.980008584 4.3606
0.3 -0.175  0.647871382 1.18165192  4.2068
0.4 -0.175  0.648227373 1.237249048 3.9966
-0.4    -0.2    0.652093788 1.841088438 4.9194
-0.3    -0.2    0.645421888 0.799100984 5.1412
-0.2    -0.2    0.642443335 0.333923846 4.6046
-0.1    -0.2    0.638571367 -0.270782761    4.8022
0   -0.2    0.648910418 1.343923923 4.845
0.1 -0.2    0.640028458 -0.043220745    5.0867
0.2 -0.2    0.644494523 0.654269212 4.2685
0.3 -0.2    0.646647546 0.990518756 4.5856
0.4 -0.2    0.648012554 1.203699525 4.2723
-0.4    -0.22   0.648346691 1.255883598 7.81
-0.3    -0.22   0.638923992 -0.215711338    7.8466
-0.2    -0.22   0.639116917 -0.185581234    6.9051
-0.1    -0.22   0.634005844 -0.983805752    7.0971
0   -0.22   0.645566299 0.821654457 6.7087
0.1 -0.22   0.642833067 0.394790427 6.7006
0.2 -0.22   0.642137584 0.286173026 5.7116
0.3 -0.22   0.642468238 0.337813057 6.7719
0.4 -0.22   0.649589404 1.44996499  5.8421
-0.4    -0.25   0.643171696 0.447676043 11.2665
-0.3    -0.25   0.624205236 -2.51442075 12.1483
-0.2    -0.25   0.6346287   -0.886530912    10.6704
-0.1    -0.25   0.626109511 -2.217019641    11.2351
0   -0.25   0.625954062 -2.241297039    11.4022
0.1 -0.25   0.629556014 -1.678760176    11.4139
0.2 -0.25   0.626682077 -2.127598832    10.8941
0.3 -0.25   0.634274094 -0.941911648    10.7257
0.4 -0.25   0.651700565 1.779676548 8.5993
-0.4    -0.275  0.602505108 -5.903449698    18.5405
-0.3    -0.275  0.589242852 -7.974689365    18.0186
-0.2    -0.275  0.608347763 -4.990969881    14.8303
-0.1    -0.275  0.59564995  -6.974057565    16.8206
0   -0.275  0.598556557 -6.520116609    16.9782
0.1 -0.275  0.606933271 -5.21187898 15.7363
0.2 -0.275  0.606268046 -5.315770747    15.1497
0.3 -0.275  0.60715145  -5.17780478 15.557
0.4 -0.275  0.619611158 -3.231903354    15.4479
-0.4    -0.325  0.44772037  -30.07703703    32.1154
-0.3    -0.325  0.491538187 -23.23376654    25.8088
-0.2    -0.325  0.515934883 -19.4235998 26.5352
-0.1    -0.325  0.513768064 -19.76200391    25.5117
0   -0.325  0.520923708 -18.64446749    24.2903
0.1 -0.325  0.512633792 -19.93914933    25.3012
0.2 -0.325  0.506195131 -20.94471071    25.2274
0.3 -0.325  0.5064044   -20.91202801    25.1006
0.4 -0.325  0.456628767 -28.6857635 32.6067
-0.4    -0.35   0.373249601 -41.70754835    40.21
-0.3    -0.35   0.428915854 -33.01384217    31.4222
-0.2    -0.35   0.445401768 -30.43914593    31.1645
-0.1    -0.35   0.470258689 -26.55710335    28.733
0   -0.35   0.45752468  -28.54584386    28.7522
0.1 -0.35   0.438996425 -31.43950372    30.345
0.2 -0.35   0.444158804 -30.63326649    29.8911
0.3 -0.35   0.452448615 -29.33860094    28.9558
0.4 -0.35   0.386020555 -39.7130379 40.0669
-0.4    -0.385  0.351766549 -45.06267518    46.3737
-0.3    -0.385  0.35470431  -44.60386882    41.5641
-0.2    -0.385  0.367019392 -42.68055448    41.8978
-0.1    -0.385  0.400259234 -37.48930485    37.3694
0   -0.385  0.392168629 -38.7528592 37.8883
0.1 -0.385  0.366377483 -42.7808049 39.9096
0.2 -0.385  0.376851806 -41.14497204    37.3136
0.3 -0.385  0.390408584 -39.02773515    36.1592
0.4 -0.385  0.377445037 -41.05232395    43.9629

"""